# how to generate pig query from sql query

Tags: apache-pig

so i work on star schema benchmark data base:
i use ubuntu 12.04, mysql 5.5 i generated this data base and related queries and create a data base similar to ssb data base i charged the tables with load infile data then try to excute the related queries with mysql and i need to execute this queries with pig latin so i have to install JDK and pig i have difficult in this point after i have to write sql queries in pig and execute with pig

example of sql query:
***select 
    sum(lo_extendedprice*lo_discount) as revenue
from 
    lineorder, dates
where 
    lo_orderdate = d_datekey
    and d_year = 1993
    and lo_discount between 1 and 3
    and lo_quantity < 25;***

Answer (score 0):

After you load the data set in pig , the next set is to apply "FILTER" where you can put all the clauses in the 'where' condition.
The below SO question will help you to find the sum.
[How to compute sum of a field in all the rows from an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898721/how-to-compute-sum-of-a-field-in-all-the-rows-from-an-alias)